# C# - Foreach loop iterating only over certain objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object, foreach

I'm studying programming right now and I had to create a snake game.

In the game, there are around 5 possible consumables for the snake and I decided to put every new `Consumable` in a `Consumable` array.

Now I wanted to iterate with `foreach` loops through the array and do something like:

```
foreach (Apple apple in consumables)
{
    renderer.DrawApple(apple);
}
```

However when there are different objects in the array like an `Apple` and a `SegmentRemover` (which is possible, because they inherit from the `Consumable` class), then the compiler iterates over the `SegmentRemover` as well and I get an invalid cast exception.

I thought since I'm declaring in the `foreach` loop that I only want to iterate over `Apple` objects, that it should work.

Are there any easy ways to get around this? Preferably without things like `var` or `typeof`, since I'm not allowed to use these yet.

Comment: What is the definition of `consumables`? what exactly is the relationship between `consumables`, `Apple` and `SegmentRemover`?

Comment: FYI var wouldnt help you at all.  What is the type of `consumables`?  Are you allowed to use LINQ to filter the list?  It would _really_ help if you posted the definition of `Apple`, `SegmentRemover` and `Consumable`

Comment: Apple and SegmentRemover are classes with an origin, that inherit from the Consumable class. Also I'm not allowed to use linq as well.

Comment: I had your same misconception when I started working with C#; it has always struck me as odd that this introduces a cast, even though I understand now why it does. The answer that suggests using the `OfType<Apple>` sequence operator is a good idea.

Comment: @Patai - did any of the solutions below help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

What you actually want is only those items that are "castable" to the type of `Apple`. For that use [`OfType<Apple>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) (uses linq):

```
foreach (Apple apple in consumables.OfType<Apple>())
{
    renderer.DrawApple(apple);
}
```

A non linq solution which will do pretty much the same is to use the [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as):

```
foreach(var item in consumbles)
{
    var apple = item as Apple;
    if(apple != null) 
    {
        renderer.DrawApple(apple);
    }
}
```

---

However IMO if all these items are placed in the same list, and as they all inherit from `Consumble` already, a better design all together, using polymorphisem, is to define for each type of `Consumable` a `draw` method as @dasblinkenlight suggested. And have specific implementations for each type. In the case of `SegmentRemover` it might be an empty implementation and in the `Apple` it might call the `renderer`.

Answer (score 3):

You could flip the logic around, letting each consumable draw itself in a renderer:

```
interface IConsumable {
    void draw(Renderer renderer);
}
class Apple : IConsumable {
    void draw(Renderer renderer) {
        renderer.DrawApple(this);
    }
}
class SegmentRemover : IConsumable {
    void draw(Renderer renderer) {
        renderer.DrawSegmentRemover(this);
    }
}
```

Now your loop can go like this:

```
foreach (IConsumable consumable in consumables) {
    consumable.Draw(renderer);
}
```

This way you invoke `Draw` polymorphically on each instance of `IConsumable`, so the code that gets executed is decided at runtime by the actual class implementing `IConsumable` interface.

Comment: I've just learned about interfaces, however I'll try to implement it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Your consumables is collection, are you trying to get to the collection with an instance of the object that stores the collection? if yes:
Try:

```
foreach (Apple apple in consumables.consumables)
{
    renderer.DrawApple(apple);
}
```